# How to provide model configuration presets in Django

Tags: django-models

so what I am trying to achieve is the following:
I have two models A and B which have a OneToOne relationship. Instances of model A are **always** created before their respective model B instances. Dependent on a parameter, I want to be able to initialize an instance of model b with different initial values.

What I've come up with is to define a ProtoTypeModel and subclass it with the actual Model like so:

```
from django.db import models
#other imports

class PrototypeB(models.Model):
   #define all fields

class B(PrototypeB):
    pass
```

By using `dict = PrototypeB.objects.filter(**my criteria).values()[0]` or a custom Serializer from Django Rest Framework, I will get a dict which I can then use to instantiate my instance of model B : `B.objects.create(**dict)`.

Is this the proper way to do so or am I missing a huge point?

Best,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon the same question on his path, here's how I did it.
First I thought about implementing the solution I mentioned above. However, researching about multi table inheritance, I found that this is actually a non functioning one.

The multi table inheritance will create an implicit OneToOne _ptr field, which will trigger cascade deleting behavior, causing my arche type models to be deleted, when an instance of B is deleted.

I went along implementing two models PrototypeB and B which works perfectly fine.